# Objective-C would serialize/restore objects with multiple references create duplicate objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, serialization, reference, save

I'm building a game and am implementing a save game function. It is a series of calls to `encodeWithCoder:` . I'm running into an issue as I'm trying to re-initialize the following data structure:

- X has `strong` reference to Y
- Y has  `strong` reference to Z
- Z has `assign` reference to X

To serialize I call `encodeWithCoder:`

- X serializes Y
- Y serializes Z

How can I restore the Z reference to X? **Is it legal to ask Z to serialize/deserialize it's reference to X, or will this create duplicate objects or infinite loop?**

Right now I'm trying to work around the issue by using universal IDs for X, so Z knows the universal ID for X, and at some point during deserialization Z would pull X out of some list by ID and assign it back to it's X reference. **Is there a better/simpler way to restore reference to X?**

Comment: How did Z get the reference to X to start with? Use the same logic when you deserialize the objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just encode the objects, they are uniquified as they are being written out. From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/archives.html):

> An object graph is not necessarily a simple tree structure. Two
>   objects can contain references to each other, for example, creating a
>   cycle. If a coder follows every link and blindly encodes each object
>   it encounters, this circular reference will generate an infinite loop
>   in the coder. Also, a single object can be referenced by several other
>   objects. The coder must be able to recognize and handle multiple and
>   circular references so that it does not encode more than one copy of
>   each object, but still regenerate all the references when decoding.
>
> To solve this problem, NSCoder introduces the concept of a root
>   object. The root object is the starting point of an object graph. To
>   encode an object graph, you invoke the NSCoder method
>   encodeRootObject:, passing in the first object to encode. Every object
>   encoded within the context of this invocation is tracked. If the coder
>   is asked to encode an object more than once, the coder encodes a
>   reference to the first encoding instead of encoding the object again.

Comment: I see, I already used this method on my root object, the problem is that my circular relationships occur deeper within object graph. :(